# wordpress tinymce visual editing window not stretched as text editing

Tags: tinymce

wp 4.1 
tinymce advance 4.1.7

I put paragraphs in the editing area under text mode without any html codes.

Then trying to see how it looks on visual mode, but visual mode does not stretch as text edit mode.

Even though it is not, the front-end pages, posts and topics on bbpress which were edited appear as expected.

How can I make visual mode stretched fully as like text mode ?

I already will thank for the one who let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution in codex. In my remembrance, was ok to simply put editor css file into child theme dir.

Now, Wordpress 4.1 asks us to do one more task of hooking an action.

put the following code into functions.php of curent theme dir.

```html
function my_theme_add_editor_styles() {
 add_editor_style( 'custom-editor-style.css' );
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_theme_add_editor_styles' );

then, put the file, custom-editor-style.css, into same dir with scripted as below:

html .mceContentBody
{max-width:99%;}
```